# Making Twitter Fabric Work in Android Studio

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-fabric

I've downloaded Android Studio and added the Fabric Plugin. However nothing to do with twitter is working in my app, it all shows up in red, as per the image:

[image]

I'm getting this message when I compile or build:

[image]

Can anyone make any guesses as to what I haven't configured properly?

I just had a look on the fabric developer website. Should I be working my way through all the stuff here?:

[android developer](https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/android)

Needless to say, I'm lost.

Comment: Post your build.gradle file.

Comment: which one? build.gradle(TwitterLogin) or build.gradle(app)?

Comment: android {
    compileSdkVersion 15
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.domain.twitterlogin"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 15
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

Comment: Check the answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/26959871/423980
Update support library from sdk manager and also add the dependency to your gradle file.

Comment: According to my SDK manager it's already installed. I've add the dependency - compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.1.0@aar') {transitive = true;}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65415/discussion-between-acl77-and-mt0s).