# Android Fabric SDK plugin conflicts with newly added Gradle plugin

Tags: android, twitter, android-gradle-plugin, twitter-fabric, gradle-plugin

I've been using the Fabric plugin for a few weeks.  Today I tried to add the [Shazam Fork Gradle plugin](https://github.com/shazam/fork) by updating my `build.gradle` as per their README instructions.

When I try to Sync Project with Gradle Files, I hit a 401 HTTP error:

> Error:Could not GET
>   'https://maven.fabric.io/repo/com/shazam/fork/fork-gradle-plugin/0.9.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml'.
>   Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized Enable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project

It seems like maybe Gradle is trying to download the Fork plugin from the Fabric.io repository instead of from Maven central?  Does anybody know the best way to fix this?  It makes me wonder if the Fabric.io repository should return a 404 instead of a 401 when a client tries to access a non-existant repository.

The symptoms are the same as for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26944483/112705), which is when adding the support library.

[image: build.gradle updates]

Comment: I don't see how this could work. I don't see fork-gradle-plugin in Maven Central, so that's why it's looking for it in Fabric.io -- it looks first in MavenCentral since that's first in the list of repositories, then it looks in Fabric.io and fails. It's rather unfriendly of Fabric.io's server to throw a 401 instead of a 404 for this, but that's a separate matter. I realize that Fork's usage instructions tell you do to only this, but I don't see how it could work. I'd take it up with Fork's author.

Comment: Scott, thanks for the quick response.  I've raised an issue with Shazam Fork: https://github.com/shazam/fork/issues/11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Shazam Fork team have now made [their plugin available in Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cshazam), and this has resolved my problem.

It's a shame that Fabric's servers throw a 401 error instead of a 404 - I expect the Gradle error message would be less confusing if Fabric returned a 404.