# Adding twitter-kit to android studio project

Tags: android, twitter

I am trying to add enable logging in with twitter to my application.
I am following [this](https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/android/twitter) manual in order to do so.
When I'm trying to sync the gradle after adding to the dependencies these lines:

```
compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.3.2@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
```

(as they instruct in their website)
I recieve this gradle error:

> Failed to resolve: com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.3.2

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to add Fabric at the top of your build.gradle - you probably already have the apply plugin: 'com.android.application' line, just put all of this stuff in its place.

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/repo' }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
  }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
repositories {
  maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/repo' }
}
```

But this is just one hurdle - next you're going to have to authenticate to Fabric itself. Basically, you started in the wrong place - Twitter wants you to start by going to https://get.fabric.io/ and integrating Fabric into your workflow.

Comment: Great!! This must be written in twitter SDK integration guide.. I wander why they didn't...

Comment: Sorry, is this completely necessary? Can someone explain what is the relationship between this Fabric and Twitter? It feels annoying to have to add all this in order to integrate the Twitter SDK

Comment: I just want to integrate a native Twitter share dialog into my app. Why the hell is it that complicated. I don't want all the Fabric stuff!

Comment: I added maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' } instead of maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/repo' }. I got that from the firebase twitter integration url. Is there any difference between the two?

Answer (score 2):

Complete Twitter integration is here. Follow the instructions. And ENJooooooY..

**<strike>https://dev.twitter.com/fabric/android/integrating</strike>** (dead link)

**UPDATE**

https://docs.fabric.io/android/twitter/overview.html

Comment: Why these docs links keep on changing. i think this is third time as far as i knew

Answer (score 0):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

buildscript {

repositories {

    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
 }
}

repositories
{
maven {
     url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
}
}
 android 
{

compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.pc2.twitterlogin"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies

{

compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.3.2@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

```
Add Plugin in Android studio From Setting -> Plugin -> Browse Repositries             
Then Search Fabric for Android 
1. Install plugin and restart Android Studio
2. After Intallation Create new project then click on Fabric icon on Android studio
3. Click Login With Twitter and create account for your app
4. Now Enjoy login with twitter work fine with your app

Logout From Twitter 

CookieSyncManager.createInstance(getApplicationContext());
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
cookieManager.removeSessionCookie();
Twitter.getSessionManager().clearActiveSession();
Twitter.logOut();
```

Answer (score 0):

I used `compile 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:3.1.1'` in the `app/build.gradle`